# Logging the log using NLog which uses WCF services

Tags: wcf, nlog

I want to log me error using Nlog dll which internally call the WCF services to log the error.

Comment: What? You want to call a WCF service to log an error using nLog?

Comment: yes in NLog config we need to configure WCF Services

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the [LogReceiverService](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/LogReceiverService-target) target. It sends log messages to a NLog Receiver Service (using WCF or Web Services).